# How to create a desktop shortcut for a command?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

I use a dongle for using internet on my kubuntu desktop. But to use the dongle, everytime I have to run MobilePartner from `/usr/local/airtel/MobilePartner` using terminal. Is there any way I can create a desktop shortcut for the command above.

Can a app do it?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a `.desktop` file in your `/home/user/Desktop/` directory that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/alex/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

This the user must be owner of this file and the executable permission must be set, see my example:

[image: example .desktop file]

And here the file:

```
user@host:~# ls -la /home/user/Desktop/firefox.desktop
-rwx------ 1 user user 9177 Dec 27 08:27 /home/user/Desktop/firefox.desktop
```

For more information see the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: but every time i have to run the command from terminal as root,how can i get root access in the above method.

Comment: Then use `gksu`. Write the Exec-part like this: `Exec=gksu /usr/local/airtel/MobilePartner`.

Answer (score 1):

**Normally**, Mobile Partner application makes a Desktop Shortcut. Certain times it may become invisible for some reasons. To solve this:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal. In the prompt type, `gksudo gedit` and make a space infront.
- In file browser go to the folder `/usr/share/applications`. Here find if there a Mobile Partner Icon.
- If present Drag and Drop it to the terminal. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- In the resulting text file, go to the line starts with `Exec=`. At the end of this line it should be `%F`. Change the content.
- Then go to the line starts with `NoDisplay=`. It should be `NoDisplay=false`. If present is `true`, change it.
- Then save the file and close.

**If there is no** such icon (Desktop configuration file) in `/usr/share/applications`, You need to create a new one.

For that, run :

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/MobileParter.desktop
```

In the resulting empty text file, Copy and Paste the following and save.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Mobile Partner
Comment=Mobile Partner Airtel 
TryExec=sudo /usr/local/airtel/MobilePartner
Exec=sudo /usr/local/airtel/MobilePartner %F
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/local/airtel/mobile.png
NoDisplay=false
MimeType=applications/php
```

There will be the icon in dash now.